# How to load Avro files into BigQuery table in Google Cloud Datalab from Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

Export BigQuery table to Cloud Storage Avro file succeeds

```
table = bq.Table(bq_table_ref)
job_id = table.extract(destination=gs_object, format='avro')
```

while import Cloud Storage Avro file into BigQuery table fails

```
table = bq.Table(bq_table_ref)
job_id = table.load(source=gs_object, source_format='avro')
```

and the alternative fails as well as

```
%%bq load -m create -f avro -p gs_object -t bq_table_ref
```

Is loading Avro files not supported within google.datalab.bigquery ?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [google.datalab.bigquery docs](http://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/datalab.bigquery.html#datalab.bigquery.Table.load), the format of the data should be ‘csv’ or ‘json’. The default is ‘csv’. You can't use 'avro' format.